# export buttons in data table header is exporting all values from dropdown list placed in header

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

I have implemented Data table plugin with export buttons. I have added column filters in header of each column.

When i export data using any export option it displays all values from that column filter drop down list,which is weird to see.

Just now I tried using

```
var data = table.buttons.exportData( {
   format: {
      header: function ( data, columnIdx ) {
         return columnIdx +': '+ data;
      }
   }
} );
```

but due to this my yadcf filter is not working.
getting error as

> Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/64dp0fc9/) for demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect header when exporting to PDF with yadcf filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940653/incorrect-header-when-exporting-to-pdf-with-yadcf-filter)

Answer (score 0):

> Link to get exact answer:[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940653/incorrect-header-when-exporting-to-pdf-with-yadcf-filter/38015961#38015961)

```
   {
        extend:    'pdfHtml5',
        title: 'Data export',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="color:red"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'PDF',
        /*footer: true,*/
        pageSize: 'letter',
        exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        modifier: {
                                    page: 'current'
                                  }
                       }
    }
```